# super + space not working in login page

Tags: gnome, login, nautilus, login-screen, 22.10

on the login page, changing the keyboard language is not possible with super + space shortcut. by pressing super + space it shows changing language popup but does not affect keyboard language.

also in Nautilus when I want to change file name, super + space not working, and append a space to the file name.

In all these cases I should change keyboard language on top bar.

Ubuntu 22.10

GNOME nautilus 43.0

GNOME 43.1

Comment: Sorry this is a very confusing question. It does seem to be 2 separate issues.

Comment: ubuntu 22.10 uses Gnome 43

Answer (score 0):

For the login page, you can add the keyboards to the `/etc/default/keyboard` file.

For example for having the French and the US (international keyboard, you would add the respective lines like this:

```
XKBLAYOUT="fr,us"
XKBVARIANT=",intl"
```

Then you will be able to switch with the `super+space`.

Comment: The problem isn't that language is not available on the login page. just the shortcut key not working there.